# Getting array index of empty objects in model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember.js and js in general. I am trying to play around with actions... More specifically, the empty objects in my IndexRoute are expressed as div elements on the template, and I have an action on the divs to call clickedSquare. How do I call the array index of any given object that is clicked in the template? I think I am missing some fundamental understanding of how routes and controllers interact. Thank you for your time.

```
App = Em.Application.create();


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        clickedSquare: function() {
            alert('You clicked square ' + ???);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you were looking for: http://jsbin.com/kelevega/5/edit

There are two approaches shown in the example, one is by using _view.contentIndex, and the other one is by using indexOf function.